# Why use try {} finally {} with an empty try block?

Tags: c#, .net

I noticed in `System.Threading.TimerBase.Dispose()` the method has a `try{} finally{}` block but the `try{}` is empty.

Is there any value in using `try{} finally{}` with an empty `try`?

http://labs.developerfusion.co.uk/SourceViewer/browse.aspx?assembly=SSCLI&namespace=System.Threading&type=TimerBase

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
internal bool Dispose(WaitHandle notifyObject)
{
    bool status = false;
    bool bLockTaken = false;
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
    try {
    }
    finally {
        do {
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_lock, 1, 0) == 0) {
                bLockTaken = true;
                try {
                    status = DeleteTimerNative(notifyObject.SafeWaitHandle);
                }
                finally {
                    m_lock = 0;
                }
            }
            Thread.SpinWait(1);
            // yield to processor
        }
        while (!bLockTaken);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process around line 2144 as well: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,2114

Answer (score 181, accepted):

From [http://blog.somecreativity.com/2008/04/10/the-empty-try-block-mystery/](http://web.archive.org/web/20130523155042/http://blog.somecreativity.com/2008/04/10/the-empty-try-block-mystery/):

> This methodology guards against a
>   Thread.Abort call interrupting the
>   processing. The MSDN page of
>   Thread.Abort says that “Unexecuted
>   finally blocks are executed before the
>   thread is aborted”. So in order to
>   guarantee that your processing
>   finishes even if your thread is
>   aborted in the middle by someone
>   calling Abort on your thread, you can
>   place all your code in the finally
>   block (the alternative is to write
>   code in the “catch” block to determine
>   where you were before “try” was
>   interrupted by Abort and proceed from
>   there if you want to).

Comment: Why not use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.begincriticalregion.aspx?

Comment: Because that wasn't available until .NET 2.0

Comment: @RobFonseca-Ensor: Because `Thread.BeginCriticalRegion()` does not *prevent* a thread from being aborted, rather tells the runtime that *if* a thread is aborted, then global state is corrupt, and the whole appdomain is up to a mercy killing.

Comment: @HansPassant: `BeginCriticalSection()` really was not there in .NET 1.x, but there is no cause and effect, that you imply in saying *because*. In fact, in .NET 1.x, even a `finally` block could have been interrupted by a thread abort. These mechanisms serve a different purpose: doing work in a `finally` prevents aborting mid-way in code, while `BeginCriticalSection()` only declares to the runtime that the global state is at risk.

Comment: If the developer has a while(true) in the finally would the abort ever complete or could an abort technically be ignored indefinitely?

Comment: Interesting.  So essentially, finally makes a block of code 'atomic' with respect to the exception handling system.  But what happens if an exception other than a ThreadAbortException is thrown during execution of the finally block?

Answer (score 65):

This is to guard against `Thread.Abort` interrupting a process. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) for this method says that:

> Unexecuted finally blocks are executed before the thread is aborted.

This is because in order to recover successfully from an error, your code will need to clean up after itself. Since C# doesn't have C++-style destructors, `finally` and `using` blocks are the only reliable way of ensuring that such cleanup is performed reliably. Remember that `using` block turns into this by the compiler:

```
try {
    ...
}
finally {
    if(obj != null)
        ((IDisposable)obj).Dispose();
}
```

In .NET 1.x, there was a chance that `finally` block will get aborted. This behavior was changed in .NET 2.0.

Moreover, empty `try` blocks never get optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: @Anton I understand that using is a best practice. But for mocking purposes, sometimes a wrapper class needs to be implemented and the disposable object becomes a private class variable. If we make this wrapper disposable, isn't GC handling the disposing of the private class variable automatically then?

Comment: @Ozkan the GC does not dispose anything automatically. You would need to implement a finalizer, typically calling a `Dispose(false);`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

Comment: @Thorarin sorry but you are wrong by saying GC not disposing (finalizing) automatically.