# A curious bit of C# code - needs some explaining

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use try {} finally {} with an empty try block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186101/why-use-try-finally-with-an-empty-try-block)

While stepping through MS .NET code I have stumbled upon this piece:

```
try { } finally 
{
  // Called in a finally because it needs to run uninterrupted in order to maintain consistency.
  queued = IOThreadScheduler.current.ScheduleCallbackHelper(callback, state);
}
```

Interesting trick. Can anyone one donate an explanation?

Answer (score 9):

This is most likely intended to execute the line in the presence of a `ThreadAbortException`.

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx):

> When this exception is raised, the runtime executes all the finally blocks before ending the thread.