# How much work in the Dispose method?

Tags: c#, dispose, correctness

How much work should be done in a Dispose method? In constructors I've always taken the stance  that you should only do what is absolutely necessary to instantiate the object. This being the case I've also always taken the approach that you should ONLY be cleaning up open resources when disposing. Closing files, freeing memory, disposing of child disposable object, etc. You shouldn't be doing lengthy processes like touching files, accessing databases and such in the Dispose method.

Am I wrong? Are those action's OK as long as you are handling any possible exceptions so they don't bubble out of the method? I just don't think doing a lot in Dispose is a good idea. I would like to know what the community thinks.

Comment: After all the discussion below I think that my ideas on Dispose may have been a little too strict and that sometimes it's OK to have a little work process during Dispose. I'm still going to focus on keeping a tight lean Dispose method but I'm now more open to doing a little more processing when absolutely needed. Thanks for all the feedback and I appreciate everyone's time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I wrong?

No, you are right. In general the Dispose method is used to clean the unmanaged resources that your class might have allocated.

But that's difficult to generalize. There are cases where the Dispose method is simply used to ensure that some operation executes. For example in ASP.NET MVC there's the Html.BeginForm helper which is used like that:

```
using (Html.BeginForm())
{

}
```

and all that the Dispose method does is render a closing `</form>` tag. So as you can see people could be creative with the pattern and it is very difficult to draw conclusions without a specific scenario.

But in the most common situations it's used to release unmanaged resources.

Comment: Well sometimes that makes sense because you know adding a string of "</form>" is fast and will not exception. What I'm concerned with is accessing of SQL or a file where you have a pretty good chance of loosing connection and causing unhandled exception or just doing too much work when all the object wants to do is Dispose. See what I'm getting at? I expect Dispose to be fast and fluid. Not to hang up in a timeout to a filestream.

Comment: @BobbyCannon, yeah, sure, for such cases you should really limit the amount of work that the method does.

Comment: @BobbyCannon: Even if an object manipulates outside entities in a fashion which is onerous to clean up, the `Dispose` method should still clean it up.  Don't blame the `Dispose` method for doing too much--either blame whoever left the entity in that state to begin with, or recognize the cleanup as being annoying but necessary.

Comment: @supercat Why is it the job of the Dispose to cleanup this state? The job of the Dispose method to cleanup the resources taken by the object. Maybe I'm being to strict on what I'm defining as "resources" but I consider that anything running in process. I don't consider SQL or file DATA to be "resources". Also remember that I'm not saying I'm right but rather curious on what you guys think. Like shanselman says I have strong convictions that are lightly held.

Comment: @BobbyCannon: If an object has a responsibility to ensure that the state gets cleaned up, and its `Dispose` method doesn't clean up the state, how is the state ever going to get cleaned up?

Comment: @supercat If for instance you had some temp files for doing some audio conversion then you should clean those up in a cleanup method. You shouldn't be relying on the dispose method to cleanup file that were used in the object. The other method members should take on that responsibility. The Dispose method should close open handles, buffers, etc. Not delete temp files which he may not even have access to when dispose is called. This is just an example. I think if the object's design "requires" the dispose method to cleanup external resources then the object has been designed incorrectly.

Comment: @BobbyCannon, don't quite agree about the temp files. You have a perfect example in the BCL itself which does exactly that - it creates temporary files and inside the Dispose method it deletes them - it's the [TempFileCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.tempfilecollection.aspx) class. So, don't try to draw general conclusions what you should do and what you should not do in the Dispose method. Everything will depend on the specific class that you are designing.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Please understand that I'm not saying that you will never do work in the Dispose. What I'm saying in that it should be rare and if you feel that the work is needed then reconsider the design to be sure. I know that certain action must be taken in the Dispose method of some objects. Like Darian's BCL example, I understand that some objects will have to delete temporary files.  Also when this work does need to occur there much be great care taken to be sure no exceptions are passed unless they are system critical. Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: @BobbyCannon: If you require the use of a separate cleanup method, how are you going to ensure that it gets called?  The `using` directives in vb.net and C# ensure `IDisposable` cleanup, even in the presence of exceptions, by using `try`-`finally` blocks. Do you expect that client code will always use explicitly-written `try`-`finally` blocks to ensure that your custom cleanup code gets called? Also, why deleting temp files qualitatively more dangerous than in closing a file which is open for writing? Both operations can fail or be blocked an arbitrarily long time by bad network connections.

Comment: @BobbyCannon: It is often good for classes to offer cleanup methods in addition to `IDisposable`, with the provisos that such methods should be used before calling `IDisposable.Dispose()` when possible, and that a successful return from `IDisposable.Dispose()` may not guarantee that cleanup was successful.  On the other hand, even if such cleanup methods are not called, `IDisposable.Dispose()` should still make a reasonable effort to clean up any outside entities to the extent possible.

Answer (score 2):

"It depends".  What kind of database/file access are we talking about?  Say for example that your disposable object is some sort of logger and you use it in the following pattern

```
using(Logger logger = new Logger())
{
    foo.PerformTask();
}
```

I think it would be perfectly acceptable for logger to write out "Log started" in the constructor "Log Completed" in Dispose.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. An object's constructor should only get the object to a instantiated state. No processing or work should be done in the constructor. If you need other work it should be in a member method. Writing to the log is too much work for a constructor. I always do this paper test. Could I instantiate 1,000,000 of this object in an loop without a lot of processing time? If the answer is no then something is wrong. I feel the same way with dispose.

Comment: @BobbyCannon I disagree. Doing some job (of course you won't access a database for instance) in the constructor is fine in some cases, and the example of the logger is actually a good example. See how Microsoft does the job in their Tracer class: http://entlib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/90009#529980
+1 for the logger

Comment: @BobbyCannon It seems that you already know the answer you want and are just looking for confirmation.

Comment: @cadrell0 Yeah I think I know the what I would consider the answer. What I'm looking for is to see if someone else could convince me otherwise. I like to be proven wrong if it makes me a better developer. So I was just curious what others thought.

Answer (score 1):

> How much work should be done in a Dispose method?

This depends, are you implementing the IDispose interface just for the convenience of a 'using' statement, or are you implementing the full IDisposable pattern?  In the later case of a full disposable pattern it is still acceptable to perform more complex actions provided that you're 'disposing' parameter is true (i.e. you are not in GC).

When you are defining a finalizer that calls the Dispose method there really is not too much to be concerned about.  Similar uses/abuses of the IDisposable interface mentioned already be others (i.e. `using (Html.BeginForm())`) are capable of performing any action.  Often this can greatly reduce code complexity and prevent coders from accidentally forgetting to perform some closing action.  One down (or up) side to this is that [code executes a little differently inside a finally block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186101/why-use-try-finally-with-an-empty-try-block).

> In constructors I've always taken the stance that you should only do what is absolutely necessary to instantiate the object.

Objects, IMHO, should be valid post construction.  So if you have a lot of work to do to construct something so be it.  Don't think of the workload involved, think of the consumer of you're object and it's usability.  Post-construction Initialize() methods suck ;)

> This being the case I've also always taken the approach that you should ONLY be cleaning up open resources when disposing. Closing files, freeing memory, disposing of child disposable object, etc. You shouldn't be doing lengthy processes like touching files, accessing databases and such in the Dispose method.

Actually let's break this down a bit...

**Disposing from the GC call to the Finalizer**

When you implement the IDisposable pattern (not the interface, the pattern, finalizer and all) you are essentially saying that your object has an unmanaged resource that nobody else knows about.  That means you have PInvoked a call to Win32's CreateFile, or maybe you called Marshal.AllocHGlobal or something like that.  Essentially you likely have an IntPtr instance member you need to do something with to prevent a memory leak.  These are the ONLY types of things that should be done when the disposing parameter is false (i.e. called from the finalizer on the GC thread).

Generally you DO NOT call the Dispose method on children.  You should not expect any child object to be valid.  Simply touching a member of the child object can accidentally 'revive' or [resurrect it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx).

So when you are writing code that executes in a Dispose method called from the Finalizer you have to be careful.  You are executing on the GC thread while the rest of your application waits for you.  You should perform as few operations as possible to release the unmanaged memory/resource and quit.  Never throw an exception and if you are calling an API that may throw you should catch any exception raised.  Propagating exceptions back to the GC will prematurely abort the finalizer thread and the remaining objects to be finalized will not have a chance to clean up.

**Disposing from the IDisposable.Dispose() method**

As I’ve already said, using the Dispose method is safe enough and can safely accommodate any amount of code/process.  This is where you would free unmanaged resources, call the dispose method of child objects, flush and close files, etc.  Most of the Dispose methods I’ve written do not have an associated Finalizer and therefore do not follow the IDisposable pattern, yet they implement IDisposable just for the convenience of the `using` statement.

> Am I wrong? Are those action's OK as long as you are handling any possible exceptions so they don't bubble out of the method? I just don't think doing a lot in Dispose is a good idea. I would like to know what the community thinks.

You are absolutely right when the dispose method in question is used from a finalizer.  You’re assertions about what you should and should not do in a Dispose method should actually be reworded to apply to anything called by a Finalizer.  The fact that this is generally done in a method called Dispose is a matter of convention, the IDisposable pattern, but these issues could easily exist in other methods used by the Finalizer.

Answer (score 0):

If an object does something to the state of some outside entities in a way which makes them more useful to that but less useful to everyone else, the `Dispose` method of the object should do whatever is necessary to restore outside those entities to more generally-useful state.  If one wishes to avoid having an object do too much work in `Dispose`, one should design the object so as never leave any outside entities in a state which would be onerous to clean up.

BTW, Microsoft likes to use the term "unmanaged resources", and gives examples, but never really offers a good definition.  I would suggest that an object holds an "unmanaged resource" if an outside entity is altering its behavior on behalf of that object, in a fashion which is detrimental to other objects or entities, and if that outside entity will continue to alter its behavior until the object stops it from doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You should lean toward the conclusion you have already come to. However there are situations where you need to ensure that services are stopped and that could include things like messages being logged for the service shutdown, or saving the current runtime state to data store. This type of disposal usually only applies to things that have a lifestyle that is application scope, meaning they exist the whole time the application is running. So there are situations outside of the expected norm. As is the case with every *rule* you should follow when writing code.

Comment: I agree. I think there will be "exception" to just about every rule. Which means you should almost never see it. When you do there should probably be a lengthy explanation (comment) on why the work is being done.