# Empty finally{} of any use?

Tags: c#, try-finally

An empty `try` has some value as explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2186101/33499)

```
try{}
finally
{ 
   ..some code here
}
```

However, is there any use for an empty finally such as:

```
try
{
   ...some code here
}
finally
{}
```

EDIT: Note I have Not actually checked to see if the CLR has any code generated for the empty `finally{}`

Comment: I don't think so it has any significance. As explained in the question, you pointed you would like to have empty try and finally with code, is to do something before thread is aborted. But empty finally will do nothing irrespective of thread is aborted or not.

Comment: Don't think so..blank finally doesn't have any use case.

Comment: It lets you use a `try` block without making any functional changes to the method. Why would anyone want a `try` block without a `catch` or `finally` is another question. I have no idea. Actually the `try/finally` is completely removed from the compiled CIL when the `finally` block is empty. Maybe there are some complicated cases when such code is compiled differently than code outside of `try`. I'm not aware of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Empty `finally` block in the `try-finally` statement is useless. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx)

> By using a finally block, you can clean up any resources that are
>   allocated in a try block, and you can run code even if an exception
>   occurs in the try block.

If the `finally` statement is empty, it means that you don't need this block at all. It can also show that your code is incomplete (for example, this is [the rule](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument12393) used in code analysis by DevExpress).

Actually, it's pretty easy to proof that the empty `finally` block in the `try-finally` statement is useless:

Compile a simple console program with this code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileStream f = null;
    try
    {
        f = File.Create("");
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}
```

Open the compiled dll in IL Disassembler (or any other tool that can show IL code) and you'll see that the compiler simply **removed the `try-finally` block**:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       12 (0xc)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldstr      ""
  IL_0005:  call       class [mscorlib]System.IO.FileStream [mscorlib]System.IO.File::Create(string)
  IL_000a:  pop
  IL_000b:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Comment: The question is use of `empty finally` like `empty try`. Not that why he has found empty finally in his code.

Comment: @Marshal I've extended the answer to explain my point in more detail. I hope, that now my answer is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The finally block is used to execute logic that should always happen regardless whether an exception is thrown or not, such as closing a connection, etc.

Therefore, having an empty finally block would have no purpose.