# Empty try {}, no catch, filled finally{} in System.Diagnostics.Process sources - what is it good for?

Tags: c#, try-catch-finally

I was browsing the sources of .Net Framework 4.7.1 `System.Diagnostics.Process` and found [this construct (line 2114ff)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,2114).

I never had the impetous to put someting in a `finally` just for the sake of it - I use it for things that *neeed to happen* even if exceptions (handled/unhandled) in the `try { ... }` part arise.

[The try-catch-finally docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally) tell about `try`, `catch` and `finally` - but nothing about this construct with an emtpy `try`. What is the purpose of the

```
try
{
    // empty
}
finallly
{
    // do something
}
```

code block?

---

**Quote:**

> ```
> // https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,2114  
>
> RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
> try {} finally {
>    retVal = NativeMethods.CreateProcess (
>            null,               // we don't need this since all the info is in commandLine
>            commandLine,        // pointer to the command line string
>            null,               // pointer to process security attributes, we don't need to inheriat the handle
>            null,               // pointer to thread security attributes
>            true,               // handle inheritance flag
>            creationFlags,      // creation flags
>            environmentPtr,     // pointer to new environment block
>            workingDirectory,   // pointer to current directory name
>            startupInfo,        // pointer to STARTUPINFO
>            processInfo         // pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION
>        );
>    if (!retVal)                            
>           errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
>    if ( processInfo.hProcess!= (IntPtr)0 && processInfo.hProcess!= (IntPtr)NativeMethods.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
>        procSH.InitialSetHandle(processInfo.hProcess);  
>    if ( processInfo.hThread != (IntPtr)0 && processInfo.hThread != (IntPtr)NativeMethods.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
>       threadSH.InitialSetHandle(processInfo.hThread);                    
> }
> ```

---

I took a peek into [Why is try {...} finally {...} good; try {...} catch{} bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128818/why-is-try-finally-good-try-catch-bad) but could not find anything related to this.

Comment: [This question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186101/why-use-try-finally-with-an-empty-try-block)

Comment: looks like a code smell to me...

Comment: @John thanks - your SO-search-foo is better then mine. Was going to close as dupe but Kevin beat me to it :o)